# Confused about K&R implementation of malloc

Tags: c, malloc

The code for function malloc() in K&R section 8.7 is below

```
void *malloc(unsigned nbytes) {
    Header *p, *prevp;
    Header *moreroce(unsigned);
    unsigned nunits;

    nunits = (nbytes+sizeof(Header)-1)/sizeof(header) + 1;
    if ((prevp = freep) == NULL) { /* no free list yet */
        base.s.ptr = freeptr = prevptr = &base;
        base.s.size = 0;
    }
    for (p = prevp->s.ptr; ; prevp = p, p = p->s.ptr) {
        if (p->s.size >= nunits) {    /* big enough */
            if (p->s.size == nunits) {    /* exactly */
                prevp->s.ptr = p->s.ptr;
            } else {    /* allocate tail end */
                p->s.size -= nunits;
                p += p->s.size;
                p->s.size = nunits;
            }
            freep = prevp;
            return (void *)(p+1);
        }
        if (p == freep)    /* wrapped around free list */
            if ((p = morecore(nunits)) == NULL)
                return NULL;    /* none left */
    }
}
```

I'm mainly confused by the "allocate tail end" part.

Suppose p->s.size = 5 and nunits = 2. According to the code, we first subtract 2 from p->s.size, advance p by 3, record allocated size at that address and return (void *)(p+1).

Let p' denote p after self-increment and * denote free space. The memory after above operations should look like this:

p * * p' * *

We've actually allocated 2 units of memory, but the remaining free space for p should be 2 instead of 3, since one unit is occupied by the header information for the allocated tail end.

So I think the line

```
p->s.size -= nunits;
```

should be replaced by

```
p->s.size -= nunits + 1;
```

Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in this line

```
nunits = (nbytes+sizeof(Header)-1)/sizeof(header) + 1;
```

That line takes the number of bytes requested `nbytes`, adds `sizeof(Header)-1` to round up, divides by `sizeof(header)` to get the number of units needed to hold `nbytes`. And finally, it adds 1 to make room for the header. So all the code after that assumes that you're reserving space for `nbytes` (plus padding if needed) plus the header.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! I've mixed up the two variables. But if so, shouldn't p self-increment p->s.size+1 instead to get to the correct position for header?

Comment: That's taken care of by the `return` statement which returns `p + 1`. Basically, the code is based on the concept of a block, which includes the header, data, and padding. It adjusts the request size at the beginning, and the pointer at the end. Everything in between uses block pointers.

Comment: Still assume p->s.size = 5. We have memory addresses indexed from 0 to 5. p is initially at 0 and it has free memory from 1 to 5. If nbytes = 2, I think p should advance to 4 and return 5. But it seems that p advances to 3 and returns 4 instead.

Comment: If `p->s.size = 5`, then we have memory addresses 0,1,2,3,4. So the header is 3 and the memory is 4.